# Check number of children in parent, not all children elements on page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find any rows that have less than 4 columns. Currently on console.log i get a list of all the 'a' elements and so the !=4 will always be true. How do i get this to check the number of children is less than 4 in each row rather than the whole page?

```
    var $row = $('.row');
    var $columns = $row.find('> a');
    if($columns.length !=  4) {
         // do stuff
        console.log($columns);
    }
```

I've tried $.each but this still has the same result.

Comment: You are talking about rows and columns, but do you have a table in your markup? Why are you using an anchor in your selector?

Comment: If you have more than one `.row` on your page, then `$row.find('> a')` will return all the anchors that are direct descendants of all the rows. If this is not what you intended, could you add more code (we like to see the real code) or provide a fiddle?

Comment: I think in first line, you get list of all `.row` elements, you should   iterate over `$row` with `for` and find `a` elements for each row. Also, sharing your `HTML` markup can help us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i read your question, should be:

```
$('.row').each(function (_, row) {
    var $columns = $(row).children('a');
    if ($columns.length < 4) {
        // do stuff
        console.log($columns);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, what you mean by columns and then talking about anchors. But if you are looking for children in $row then you can use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and add the selector e.g.

```
$row.children(".class_or_type_of_the_children_youwant")
```

and then check for the length where you will use lower than instead not equal mark `<`.

Also not to forget to use a unique selector. If you have more classes named row, your script will be fired everytime jquery will go through the DOM.